# Paging embedded objects from nested array

Tags: mongodb

I am relatively new to mongodb, and wondering of its possible to query the BusinessDetails collection below in a way that for business with _id: 6164bd360ab23b1482e1f10a I can page its embedded customer objects , say 10 customers at a time?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6164bd360ab23b1482e1f10a"),
    "name" : "Biz1",
    "user" : {
        "$ref" : "jhi_user",
        "$id" : "user-1"
    },
    "customers" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "customer_details",
            "$id" : ObjectId("6164bd150ab23b1482e1f109")
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "customer_details",
            "$id" : ObjectId("6164bd080ab23b1482e1f108")
        },
        {..},{..},{..}

    ],
    "_class" : "com.mycompany.seol.domain.BusinessDetails"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $slice

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("6164bd360ab23b1482e1f10a")
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      customers: {
        "$slice": [
          "$customers",
          0, // position
          1  // limit
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgN6GTTBmRD)**

Comment: oh cool @varman , do I always have to return the BusinessDetails wrapper or is it possiblt to return purely a CustomerDetails array from the query ?